# copy entity in entity framework?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, entity

For example I have a wpf window bound to an customer Entity (let suppose it's cus1). Then I load another entity from context :

```
customer cus2 = context.customers.where(x=>x.id=10).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I want cus1 = cus2 ? I can do this way :

```
cus1.name = cus2.name;
cus1.address = cus2.address;
...
...
```

This way meets my case (the content of textboxs in the form change immediately into values of cus2) but I wonder if there is anyway to make it shorter since cus1=cus2 doesn't work ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use Serialization or Reflection, to do it on your own. However both oof the methods are slower then writing it directly.

Take a look at this article. Maybe you will find it helpful:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CloningLINQ2Entities.aspx

Edit:
Btw. Remember, using using MemberwiseClone, in case of ReferenceTypes will effect in copying the references, not objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the memberwise Clone method to make a shallowcopy of a business object:
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx

Comment: This doesn't help. the text of textboxs in the form doesn't change immediately.

Comment: What does your binding look like? Have you implemented INotifyPropertyChanged Interface`?

Comment: Yes, INotifyPropertyChanged has been implemented in auto-generated code by Entity Framework 4. My controls are bound directly into an entity. As I said, so far only this trick works : cus1.name = cus2.name;
cus1.address = cus2.address;
...
but I am looking for a better method not require to assign every properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the values of a Customer entity in memory with the newest values in the datastore you can use the Refresh method on your ObjectContext.

Here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx).

In your case it would look like:

```
context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, cus1);
```

If you really want to map two entities you could have a look at [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/). AutoMapper will help you by automatically mapping entities to each other with a default setup that you can tweak to your needs.